# Migrating ssas cube to iccube. is there any equivalent to SCOPE() in icCube?

Tags: iccube

I am migrating SSAS cube into icCube. can anyone suggest to how to write SSAS's SCOPE() functionality into icCube? is there any equivalent functionality available in icCube?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073918/porting-multidimensional-ssas-to-iccube-scope-equivalent-other-gaps-issues

Answer (score 0):

Just see this question now... sorry.

No, there is no such thing as a SCOPE function.
Instead, I use an IF ... THEN ... ELSE condition in the definitions of my calculated members, hereby getting similar results as the SCOPE functionality.

Hope that helps.